# How to assign kendo combobox a value

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using the 2016.3.914.440 version of kendo and have a question on the ComboBox. If my datasource only returns a single value, how can I assign that to the ComboBox so the user doesn't need to enter a value? I tried the .SelectIndex(0), but that works under all situations, so I thought in the .DataBound I would check for the record count and if = 1 then I wanted to assign to the ComboBox.
The code I have is the following.

```
    @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
      .Name("FAList")
      .Placeholder("Select Fiscal Agency...")
      .DataTextField("Text")
      .DataValueField("Value")
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:50%;" })
      .Filter("startswith")
      .AutoBind(true)
      .MinLength(3)
      .DataSource(source =>
      {
          source.Read(read =>
          {
              read.Action("GetUserAgencyList", "Entities");
          })
          .ServerFiltering(true);
      })
          .Events(e => e
            .Change("onFAChange")
            .DataBound("onFADataBound")
            )
```

)

But I don't know how to finish the onFADataBound event

```
    function onFADataBound(e) {
    var dropdown = $("#FAList").data("kendoComboBox");
    var count = dropdown.dataSource.data().length

    alert('FA Count: ' + count)
}
```

So how would I find the text and value of the datasource record and assign that to the DataTextField and DataValueField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the first item via the [`select`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#methods-select) method.

```
function onFADataBound(e) {
    if (e.sender.dataSource.view().length == 1) {
        e.sender.select(1);
    }
}
```

Note that the selected item's index will be `1` if you have an [`optionLabel`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#configuration-optionLabel) (placeholder) and `0` otherwise.

Comment: dimodi, thank you but using your code made no difference in the combobox, the placeholder was still the value.

Comment: I had to change the e.sender.select to be (0)